# Locking mutex in one thread and unlocking it in the other

Tags: pthreads, mutex

Will this code be correct and portable?

```
void* aThread(void*)
{
    while(conditionA)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex1);
        //do something
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex2);
    }
}

void* bThread(void*)
{
    while(conditionB)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex2);
        //do something
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex1);
    }
}
```

In the actual application I have three threads - two for adding values to an array and one for reading them. And I need the third thread to display the contents of the array right after one of the other threads adds a new item.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not. If thread A gets to mutex_unlock(2) before thread B got to mutex_lock(2), you are facing undefined behavior. You must not unlock another thread's mutex either.

The [pthread_mutex_lock Open Group Base Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) says so:

> If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL [...] If a thread  attempts  to  unlock  a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behavior results.

Comment: Ok. But what about unlocking mutex that had been locked in another thread? Undefined behaviour as well?

Comment: Like it said: "if a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked ... UB"

Answer (score 8):

As [user562734's answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608843/locking-mutex-in-one-thread-and-unlocking-it-in-the-other/4608912#4608912), the answer is no - you cannot unlock a thread that was locked by another thread.

To achieve the reader/writer synchronisation you want, you should use condition variables - `pthread_cond_wait()`, `pthread_cond_signal()` and related functions.

Comment: Semaphores are also sometimes useful for situations where you want to be able to "unlock another thread's lock". They're actually a great workaround for the fact that the documented recommended usage of `pthread_atfork` invokes undefined behavior. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations do allow locking and unlocking threads to
be different.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> 
#include <mutex> 

using namespace std;

mutex m;

void f() {m.lock();   cout << "f: mutex is locked" << endl;}

void g() {m.unlock(); cout << "g: mutex is unlocked" << endl;}

main()
{
      thread tf(f);    /* start f                           */
      tf.join();       /* Wait for f to terminate           */
      thread tg(g);    /* start g                           */
      tg.join();       /* Wait for g to terminate           */
}
```

This program prints

f: mutex is locked
g: mutex is unlocked

System is Debian linux, gcc 4.9.1. -std=c++11.

Comment: Does the implementation of gcc 4.9.1 says about it explicitly? If no and you've got your answer just from experiments then it's still UB, even though in this case it appears to be working.