# Rails 3 error : Attempt to unlock a mutex which is locked by another thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mutex

I'm working on Rails 3.2.9 app . Here we have to excute selected test cases.It is done by calling an action called execute_testcases. Mutex is used to avoid collision in different executions. But suddenly the execution has stopped working, it just pops a cmd window n closes it (opening cmd is part of code but it shud close down once execution is done) . Sometimes in the browser i get this error

```
Attempt to unlock a mutex which is locked by another thread
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2012-11-10) at localhost:3000
```

When i traced the execution  code i saw that it either stops at point 1 or point 2 (referred below in code )
So i have added only the required code for your reference. If you need some more code pls let me know..

The same code works fine in othe machines.. Just in my machine i get this error. Please help me in solving this error

accountcontroller.rb:

```
 @@lock = Mutex.new
 @@another_test_running = false

 def execute_testcases
    file_names = []
    originalfile_filewithtime = []
    original_file_map = {}
    originalfile_filewithtime = params[:excelfile]
    for value in originalfile_filewithtime
      original_file, file_with_time = value.split(',')
      original_file_map[file_with_time] = original_file
      file_names << file_with_time
    end
    copy_selected_excel_sheets_to_isaf(file_names)
    i = 0
    while(@@another_test_running && i < MAX_TIMEOUT) do
      sleep 1
      i = i + 1
    end
    @@another_test_running = true
    puts "STARTED EXECUTING #{file_names}"
    @@lock.synchronize do ###### POINT 1
      update_master_suite_file(file_names)
      Dir.chdir(SAF_DIR)
      system("START cmd /C ant ^| tee #{self.current_user.username}.log 2>&1")
      sleep 15 #To avoid collision with other SAF executions
      @@another_test_running = false
   end
   wait_for_test_execution_to_complete(900) ###### POINT 2
   show_output(file_names, original_file_map)

    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html :subject_list, :partial => 'show_output', :locals => {:new_file_map => @new_file_map}
      page.visual_effect :highlight,  'subject_list', :duration => 2
    end
  end  

 def wait_for_test_execution_to_complete(timeout)
   test_exec_log_file = SAF_DIR + self.current_user.username + ".log"
   i = 0
   text =  File.exist?(test_exec_log_file)? File.read(test_exec_log_file) : "" 
   while(!text.include?("stop-server:") && i < timeout)#### POINT 2
     sleep 2
     i = i + 2
     text =  File.exist?(test_exec_log_file)? File.read(test_exec_log_file) : ""
   end
   #Further, wait to see BUILD SUCCESSFUL or FAILED message
   j = 0
   while(!(text.include?("BUILD SUCCESSFUL") || text.include?("BUILD FAILED")) && j < 30 )
     sleep 2
     j = j + 2
     text =  File.exist?(test_exec_log_file)? File.read(test_exec_log_file) : ""
   end
   #delete the log file 
   File.delete(test_exec_log_file)
end
```

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4608912/1379394 maybe that's it.

Comment: Thank u.. ll look into tat